# How to modify a function that works on RGB images to make it work for a monochrome image?

Tags: python, pandas, image, dataframe, image-processing

Below code works correctly for a RGB Image (for shapes: 512x512x3). What I need to do is to make it work for a single channel monochrome image. (for shape: 512x512) Which parts should I modify?

```
def get_triangle_colour(triangles, image, agg_func=np.median):
    """
    Get's the colour of a triangle, based on applying agg_func to the pixels
    under it
    :param triangles: scipy.spatial.Delaunay
    :param image: image as array
    :param agg_func: function
    :return: colour list
    """
    # create a list of all pixel coordinates
    ymax, xmax = image.shape[:2]
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmax), np.arange(ymax))
    pixel_coords = np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]

    # for each pixel, identify which triangle it belongs to
    triangles_for_coord = triangles.find_simplex(pixel_coords)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "triangle": triangles_for_coord,
        "r": image.reshape(-1, 3)[:, 0],
        "g": image.reshape(-1, 3)[:, 1],
        "b": image.reshape(-1, 3)[:, 2]
    })
    
    #find the median color of the triangle
    by_triangle = (
        df
            .groupby("triangle")
        [["r", "g", "b"]]
            .aggregate(agg_func)
            .reindex(range(n_triangles), fill_value=0)
        # some triangles might not have pixels in them
    )

    return by_triangle.values / 256
```

Comment: As a really quick, easy and hugely memory-inefficient first stab that requires no thinking, you could pass an RGB version of your greyscale image with `np.dstack((grey,grey,grey))`

Comment: I think that is the only possible way. If you answer to my question, I can accept it as an answer. It works at least.

Comment: Let's leave it a little bit and I'll put it as an answer in a couple of days - there are some clever folk on StackOverflow who may be able to answer better and who may be put off answering if they see your question as answered with my idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a really quick, easy and hugely memory-inefficient first stab that requires no thinking, you could pass an RGB version (where R=G=B) of your greyscale image with:

```
np.dstack((grey,grey,grey))       # or save a few keystrokes with np.dstack([grey]*3)
```