# Converting 2D array into 3D by repeating same layer 3 times

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array of shape (512,512). I need to convert this to shape (512,512,3). All values of 2d dimension will be repeated on other two dims. How can I do this in python?

Comment: it would work for your case `np.dstack([a,a,a])`

Comment: i assume it is related to your question from an hour ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68663420/how-to-modify-a-function-that-works-on-rgb-images-to-make-it-work-for-a-monochro

Comment: yes. It is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using np dstack

it would work for your case

```
np.dstack([a,a,a])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `array[..., None].repeat(3, -1)`